# Remove Dictionary Object if value inside object is not respecting condition

Tags: python, dictionary, filter

I have a dictionary were the "ID" represents the main structure identifier. Basically what I want to do is to loop through it, find if one of the values inside each of the ID's is in the correct format, and if not, remove the entire object.

Here is the structure of my dictionary:
[image: Dictionary]

As you can see, "id" is the main key of each object. In my case I'm trying to see if the sub-key "prezzo" is int he correct format.

Correct "prezzo": "100000" <--- Just an integer
Wrong "prezzo": "da 100000 - 100000" char, spaces and double numbers. In this case I wanted to remove completely the object connected to the id, so in on 25 id's, number 3, 7 and 15 have the "prezzo" value wrong, they will be popped out of the dictionary...

I'm trying different solution, but ultimately am still not good enough with dictionaries, any suggestions on how to filter it out?

Thanks and have a lovely day!

Comment: Cause it is a python dictionary

Comment: If you have already tried different solutions you should post one of them here and specify why its not working.

Comment: @quamrana I tried filtering them with an if statement, but I completely butchered my syntax, so it would not be useful to anybody.

Comment: You mean python always complains about a syntax error no matter what changes you make?

Comment: @quamrana I mean that I'm sure the syntax I used, the key words and order of things is wrong and that my "solution" is in reality me smashing my head in a wall for nothing. So, if you understand this, I'm frustrated, can't seem to understand how to approach dictionaries in this specific case and google has not been so lucky these days :/

Comment: I'm saying that if you have code that runs, then it is worth posting because you can describe what it actually does and compare that to what behaviour you are really after. If you can't get past syntax errors, then we might still be able to help.

Comment: @quamrana, the code does NOT run. Ok? I'm sorry, it won't work, think of it as NON existent.

Comment: Then you should look up dictionary comprehensions. They can have a filter element to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this minimal example helps. It basically tries to convert each value of the key `prezzo` to an integer. If possible it will be added to the resulting dictionary. As you see also a floating point number is not a valid entry.

Find infos on dictionaries in python [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

```
dic={0:{'id':1,'prezzo':'da 30000 - 70000'},
     1:{'id':12,'prezzo':'10000'},
     2:{'id':17,'prezzo':'da 10000 - 12000'},
     3:{'id':25,'prezzo':'7.5'}}

result_dic ={}

for k,v in dic.items():
    try:
        int(v['prezzo'])
        result_dic[k]=v
    except ValueError:
        pass
        
print(result_dic)
```

Output:

```
{1: {'id': 12, 'prezzo': '10000'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    original_dicts = [{"id":1,"prezzo":"da 165000 - 25400"},
         {"id":2,"prezzo":"da 290000 - 320000"},
         {"id":3,"prezzo":"150000"},
         {"id":4,"prezzo":"10000"}]
    formated_dicts=[]
    unformated_dicts=[]
    for pos in range(len(original_dicts)):
         #checking for id
         if original_dicts[pos]["id"] and "id" in original_dicts[pos].keys():
              try:
                   #taking prezzo integer type only
                   int(original_dicts[pos]["prezzo"])
                   formated_dicts.append(original_dicts[pos])
              except:
                   unformated_dicts.append(original_dicts[pos])
         else:
              print('some of dictionaries dont have "id"')
    print(formated_dicts)
    print(unformated_dicts)

Output:
[{'prezzo': '150000', 'id': 3}, {'prezzo': '10000', 'id': 4}]
[{'prezzo': 'da 165000 - 25400', 'id': 1}, {'prezzo': 'da 290000 - 320000', 'id': 2}]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).